# Qt5 won't compile on windows 8

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I just downloaded QT for the first time. I installed the new 5.0RC2 SDK. I created a new project and set the compiler to mingw `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe` http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-tool-chains.html

But if I try to compile it I get tons of error message that look like this

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0-rc2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\GL\main.cpp:8: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7QWidget4showEv'
```

I also set the compiler in kit to mingw and the device type to desktop.

Any ideas what went wrong?

Edit:

Okay I probably know the problem. http://qt-project.org/downloads QT5 is only available for vs2010.( It's a little bit hidden). I just try QT 4.8 for mingw then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this line in the .pro

```
 CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += "C:\\Qt\\4.8.3\\lib\\QWidget4.a"
```

replace the path to the lib folder in yours. and `QWidget4.a` from similar one that the error says and available in the lib folder.

this is just a suggestion. have a try.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered yourself, Qt5.0.0 is currently only released for VS2010 on Windows. There are some problems with compiling the webkit component for MinGW. If you can live without Webkit (embedded browser) you can compile it yourself (I just did that on a fresh Win8 install for both 64bit and 32bit MinGW). All of this requires a bit of very 'Unixy' fiddling that not all Windows users may feel up to - but, heck, you want to use MinGW instead of MSVC anyway!.

Since Stackoverflow will not allow me to post more than one link, I posted my recipe here:
http://silmor.de/qtstuff.qt5mingw.php